# C# How to change playback rate of “Windows Media Player” control in winform to values less than 0.5

Tags: c#, winforms, video, combobox, playback

I want to creat combobox to select playback rate of video displayed in winform at values 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1,2,4,8.

I use code:

```
 mediaVideo.settings.rate = Double.Parse(cbSpeed.Text);
```

But I found that playback rate can not be set less than 0.5
Are there any way to set it at a value

0.1 ---> 0.4

Answer (score 0):

It seems to depend on the video format and the file location. See the documentation for more infos:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/wmplibiwmpsettings-iwmpsettings-rate--vb-and-c

I tried it and for a mp4 file on my computer and set the rate to 0.1. Media player control played the video at 0.125 so i think it selects the most suitable playback rate. Maybe the version makes any difference,too. i used "12.0.18362.449"